# php scale image based on user input

Tags: php, math, gd

I have an image created dynamically with GD. Its width is always constant at 750px but I need to scale it's height based on user input of length (2" to 64") and height (2" to 48").

So the image must always scale out to 750px wide which we shall call 100% so if a user chose 2" x 2" or 10" by 10" for instance, then the image is 750px Wide x 750px High, a square.

The issue I am having trouble wrapping my mind around is say they select 42 x 16 for instance.  In this case the 42" represents 100% of width of the image which is 750px so how do I now calculate the height based on the number 16" to be in scale ?  Is it as simple as the percentage difference between 42 and 16 ?  Tried that and I cant seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out .. simple math .. sorry but some days

```
$x= 16/42*100;
$height=($x/100*$width);
```